# Spaces in links using perl and html

Tags: html, perl, hyperlink, spaces

I have a problem with spaces using perl. I'm taking my informations from a db and I'm using them for a query string, but if there is a space, I can't validate my page.

```
<a href="fish.cgi?fish=White Shark">White Shark</a>
```

Is there something I can do?

Comment: urlencode the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your URLs into [URI](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) objects which will take care of all escaping and normalization for you.  They can also be used as strings.

```
use URI;

# Prints fish.cgi?fish=White%20Shark
print URI->new("fish.cgi?fish=White Shark");
```

I'd recommend this over individually escaping URIs.  Once you have a URI object, you know it's safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the spaces in links with `%20` which is the URL-encoded version for a space. You may have to strip this out again after it's been posted, not quite sure.

Example: `www.google.ca/this site` would be encoded as `www.google.ca/this%20site`

So your version would be `fish.cgi?fish=White%20Shark`, this should post properly.

Comment: Thanks Amon, first answer of the day, pretty sleepy :)